# What is meant by /*: * */ inside function argument?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a existing project , and see this type of function export inside any file. So what does this syntax mean?

```
export default (variables /*: * */ = variable) => {
...
}
```

Comment: See https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/2188

Comment: `/*` indicates the start of a comment. `*/` indicates the end of a comment.

Comment: @certainPerformance disagree, far more specific

Comment: @JonasWilms The code looks like it just has an inline comment in the argument list, where the argument list has one default argument - without more context, I don't see how it's anything more than that?

Comment: From an external point of view, I would understand that like some type information, here, 'any'

Comment: It does look like some sort of annotation, but I doubt we can tell what it is since it doesnt say much. Do you see a pattern in the code where this is repeated or any different than just *?

Comment: @certainPerformance 5 people disagree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just an inline comment, starting with `/*` and ending with `*/`.

If you are using Flow to type your JavaScript project, then this is interpreted as a [comment type annotation](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/comments/#toc-comment-type-annotation).

Here it means that the `variables` parameter is of type `*`.

The asterisk type in Flow (`*`) is the [existential type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-existential-type).

> An existential type is used as a placeholder to tell Flow to infer the type.